# Z-index preventing on hover attribute on another element

Tags: html, css, z-index

I have two different elements (div class="") within a larger container.

Let's call them div class="overlay_container" and div class="title." The div class="overlay_container" has a subclass, .image, which creates an overlay over the entire larger container on hover.

The div class="title" has a z-index of 10,000 and lies over .image and therefore over the overlay. Unfortunately, when you hover over "title," the subclass overlay image underneath disappears.

I know the problem is obviously that the "title" div is right over the other divs and therefore the on hover will disappear due to the z-index. But how do I fix this? How do I make it so that when you hover over the "title," the .image overlay still appears?

If your answer involves jQuery, could you please tell me where to put the script (before the /head tag)? Thanks!

Comment: It looks as if your overlay should be triggered by an event (:hover) on the larger parent container, rather than a child element?

Comment: But would that work if there is a title overlaid on top of the parent container? Wouldn't it still cause the hover to be blocked when you hover over the child "title" container?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Adding `pointer-events:none;` to the title div might work?

Looks like most browsers recognise it, except for....dun dun dun...IE: http://caniuse.com/#search=pointer-events

Comment: It works! Thanks so much for this; have never heard of this fix before. And nobody cares about IE, so that's OK.

Comment: haha, my mom cares about IE!!! So, your saying you don't want my mom to click on your links?!